# How do I rotate the legend in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Instead of showing the legend on the bottom under my chart, I want to show it to the left of the y axis, rotated 90 degrees. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a custom legend:

```
$("#a1").click(function() {
    $('.highcharts-legend-item:nth-child(1)').click();
    $(this).toggleClass("leg-clicked");
  });
```

Use this property in CSS to rotate the legend:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

Please check the following [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/0djtf6kv/):

```
$(function() {

  $("#a1").click(function() {
    $('.highcharts-legend-item:nth-child(1)').click();
    $(this).toggleClass("leg-clicked");
  });

  $('#container').highcharts({

    series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }]
  });
});
```

Be sure to deactivate Highcharts' legend in CSS:(otherwise, you will get two legends)

```
.highcharts-legend {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that highcharts can do this itself. Will make a custom legend instead. Thanks!