# Highcharts: To rotate the chart 90 degree but also redraw it

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a button that allows me to turn the chart from portrait orientation to landscape. 
So what I did is to add a class to the chart when button is clicked.

`transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);`

It did but the chart went like this
[Rotated 90 degrees, but the chart didn't redraw to 
stretch full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRFRH.png)

And this will be what I wanted, [Rotated 90 degrees, and fully stretched to the bottom of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQER4.png)

I wondered if there is a way to do so, by either using highchart's API or JS. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add some example code instead of only pictures. It makes it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: Btw, because by doing so (rotate90 degrees) my plots don't seem to work, it still remains in the portrait mode(horizontal) instead of vertical.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xjk9q05b/ Here is the code, and how can I make it turn 90degrees and also redraw. Thank man

Comment: your code works https://jsfiddle.net/wko46kb3/, just add class `full` to highcharts

Comment: @Deep 3015 I did but kinda using the toggle class way, and the result would be different from adding class `full` in the first place. Try it on a browser with the mobile view you will see what I'm trying to say. And the plotoption just didnt work at all....

Comment: where is issue https://imgur.com/a/D0nLuwm

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to do with my full-screen button! But instead of using the rotation function from the browser I would like my full-screen button to have the equivalent effect! Basically, it remains in portrait mode until the full-screen button has been clicked, then the chart rotates! So even with your device is in portrait mode, it displays in landscape mode.... and sorry if I illustrated badly its my second language

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EPW7Rxg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, if I understood you properly, but are you trying to change the chart orientation on a button click? I am not familiar with highcharts, but having a quick look at their API, something like this should be enough:

```js
// ...
var hc = Highcharts.chart('container', { /* your options */ });
// ...
$('#goFS').click(function () {
    var w = 400;
    var h = 800;
    hc.update({
        chart: {
            height: h,
            width: w,
            inverted: true
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of hardcoded sizes, you could probably read and use the size of the container or the window, depending on your goal.

Comment: Is there way to have inverted applied to the legends as well? I have tried inverted and rotation and doesnt seem to work

Comment: It looks like highcharts does not support rotating the legend natively, so you would need to make your own legend. There is a similar question answered already on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998966/how-do-i-rotate-the-legend-in-highcharts

Comment: but my legend requires parameters from the code.... I don't think I am able to use it that way, is there any other options to rotate 90degrees? cuz i need it with my tooltip as well, really need some help here it's due tmr  ~~

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EsIyhlm   need the legend to locate under the date axis with 90 degree turn

Comment: If you feel the solution to rotate the legend is not suitable, feel free to post a new question. You would want to refer to that answered question and explain why it is not suitable, so the mods won't close it as a duplicate.